# Problem with paragraphs and marginnote

Tags: paragraphs, marginpar

I created a layout with marginnotes. On the end of the page the paragraph (here Paragraph B) following the marginnote (D) will automatic jump to the next page. Example:

[image]

How can I inhibit that? I'd like to have the paragraph B just following paragraph A and if nessesary split into parts so that the page is filled down to the bottom.

Maybe there is a better solution for this than working with marginnotes. Paragraphs A, B, C always belong together and the marginnote on the side will be the word-by-word translation starting on to of B.

The code I use:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{reledmac}% Nummerierung
\usepackage{multicol} % just to get narrow columns on one page
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{xltxtra} 
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text} % ditto
\setmainfont{Gandhari Unicode} %could be any Unicode font

\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage{english}
    \setotherlanguage{sanskrit}% some Sanskrit embedded in it.
% These will call appropriate hyphenation.
    \newfontfamily\devanagarifont{Sanskrit 2003}

  \usepackage{geometry}  


\setlength\parindent{0pt}

%marginnote
\newcommand{\rand}[1]{\marginpar{\small\vspace{6pt}\textit{#1}}}

%Definition Paragraph
\newcommand{\block}[4]{{\rand{#4}\begin{sanskrit}\textbf{#1}\end{sanskrit}}\\ 
{\textbf{#2}}\\
#3\\\\}

%Definition subtitel of a paragraph
\newcommand{\subtitel}[3]{{\rand{#3}}\vspace{-6pt}\begin{center}
\textbf{{\Large #1}}
\vspace{0pt}

{{\small #2}}
\vspace{12pt}
\end{center}
}


\begin{document}

\newgeometry{outer=9.5cm, inner=3cm, heightrounded, marginparwidth=7cm, marginparsep=1cm}

\subtitel{gaṇeśa gāyatrī}{Gāyatrī-Mantra auf Gaṇeśa}{\textbf{Gaṇa}: göttliche Heerscharen. \textbf{Īśa}: Herr, Meister, Göttlichkeit; besitzen. \textbf{Gāyatrī}: Name einer berühmten Klasse von Mantras.}

\block{ॐ तत् पुरुषाय विद्महे वक्रतुण्डाय धीमहि।
\\
तन्नो दन्ती प्रचोदयात्॥}{oṃ tat puruṣāya vidmahe vakratuṇḍāya dhīmahi\\
tanno dantī pracodayāt}{Mögen wir Wissenheit über die bezeugende Instanz erlangen,
mögen wir unsere Aufmerksamkeit auf den mit dem gebogenen Rüssel halten, möge uns der mit den Stosszähnen zum Ziele führen.}{\textbf{Tad}: dieser. \textbf{Puruṣa}: Mensch, die Essenz des Menschen. \textbf{Vidhmahe}: [1. Pers. Pl. Pres. c2 Atm.: √vid] möge ich finden, entdecken,
erhalten, wissen, fühlen. \textbf{Vakra}: gebogen, verdreht. \textbf{Tuṇḍa}: Rüssel. \textbf{Dhīmahe}: [1. Pers. Pl. Opt. C4: √dhī] halten, platzieren; den Geist auf etwas ausrichten. \textbf{Tad}: dieser. \textbf{Nas}: uns. \textbf{Dantī}: Stosszähne habend. \textbf{Pracodayāt}: [3. Pers. Opt.] antreiben, anstiften, ermutigen,
induzieren, überzeugen, ankündigen, inspirieren, zum Ziel führen.}

\block{एते गन्धपुष्पे ॐ गं गणपतेये नमः}{ete gandhapuṣpe om gaṁ gaṇapataye namaḥ}{Mit diesen wohlriechenden Blumen verneige ich mich vor dem Anführer der Gaṇas.}{\textbf{Ete}: diese.\textbf{Gandha}: riechend, wohlriechend. \textbf{Puṣpe}: Blumen. \textbf{Gaṇapateye}: Anführer der Gaṇas. \textbf{Namas}: meine Ehrerbietung, meine Verneigung.}

\subtitel{gaṇeśa dhyānam}{Kontemplation auf Gaṇeśa}{\textbf{Gaṇa}: göttliche Heerscharen. \textbf{Īśa}: Herr, Meister, Göttlichkeit; besitzen. Dhyāna: Meditation, Kontemplation, Versenkung.}

\block{ॐ खर्व्वं स्थूलतनुं गजेन्द्र\\
वदनं लम्बोदरं सुन्दरं}{om kharvvaṃ sthūlatanuṃ gajendra\\
vadanaṃ lambodaraṃ sundaraṃ}{Ich preise den Kleinen, den mit dem stämmigen Körper, den mit dem Gesicht des Elefantenkönigs, den Dickbäuchigen, den Wunderschönen.}{\textbf{Kharva}: kurz, klein, zwergenhaft; verletzt, verstümmelt. \textbf{Sthūla}: die Grösse, Dicke, Stämmigkeit. \textbf{Tanu}: Körper. \textbf{Gaja}: Elephant. \textbf{Indra}: Eroberer, Bezwinger. \textbf{Vadana}: Gesicht; Aussehen, Erscheinung; Spitze eines Dreiecks. \textbf{Lambodara}: dickbäuchig. \textbf{Sundara}: wunderschön.}

\block{प्रस्यन्दन्मदगन्धलुब्ध\\
मधुपव्यालोलगण्डस्थलम्।}{prasyandanmadagandhalubdha\\
madhupavyālolagaṇḍasthalam}{Ich preise Den, von Dem ein verrücktmachender Wohlgeruch hervorströmt, welcher die Bienen begehrend seine Wange umschwärmen lässt.}{\textbf{Prasyanda}: hervorströmen, runtertropfen. \textbf{Mada}: Trunkenheit, Laster, Arroganz, Stolz, Dünkel; Verrücktheit, Leidenschaft; trunkene, ekstatische Liebe zu Gott. \textbf{Gandha}: Duft, Wohlgeruch, Geruchsinn. \textbf{Lubdha}: verwirrt, verblüfft, begehrend. \textbf{Madhupa}: Honigtrinker, Biene. \textbf{Vyālola}: sich wälzen, zittern, beben. \textbf{Gaṇḍa}: Wange, Gesichtsseite. \textbf{Sthala}: Platz, Oberfläche, Erhebung.}

\block{दन्ताघातविदारितारिरुधिरैः\\ 
सिन्दूरशोभाकरं वन्दे शैलसुतासुतम}{dantāghātavidāritārirudhiraiḥ\\
sindūraśobhākaraṃ vande śailasutāsutam}{Ich preise Den, welcher mit dem Stosszahn bis auf das Blut zerfetzt und dessen Kumkum hell erglänzt. Ihn preise ich, den Sohn der Tochter des heiligen Berges.}{\textbf{Danta}: Stosszahn, Elfenbein. \textbf{Ghāta}: zerstören, verletzen. \textbf{Vidāritā}: aufbrechen, zerreissen, zerteilen. \textbf{Rudhira}: rot sein, blutig, blut-rot. \textbf{Sindūra}: Kumkum. \textbf{Śobhā}: brilliant, leuchten. \textbf{Kara}: Hand, bewirkend, tuend, vollziehend. \textbf{Vand}: teilen, umgeben, respektvoll grüssen, verehren, preisen. \textbf{Śaila}: Hügel, Berg. \textbf{Sutā}: Tochter. Suta: Sohn.}

\block{गणपतिं सिद्धिप्रदं कामदं॥}{gaṇapatiṃ siddhipradaṃ kāmadaṃ}{Er ist der Herrscher der Gaṇas, der Gewährer der Vollendung, der Erfüller aller Wünsche.}{\textbf{Gaṇas}: Name für die göttlichen Heeresscharen. \textbf{Pati}: Ehemann, Herr, Meister, Besitzer. \textbf{Siddhi}: Erfolg, Erfüllung, Vollendung; verborgene Kräfte. \textbf{Pradā}: Weggeben, geben, offerieren, schenken. \textbf{Kāmada}: das Gewünschte erfüllend.}

\end{document}
```

I hope I could ask my question comprehensible. Any suggestions?

Comment: you have titled widowpenalty but your image does not show any widow lines (last line of a paragraph at the top of the page) I am not clear what you are asking to change? (your marginal notes will not split over a page)

Comment: Note `\usepackage{xltxtra} % standard for nearly all XeLaTeX documents` despite the comment it is recommended not to load `xltxtra` these days, apart from `fontspec` most of the packages it loads are not needed now.

Comment: I get `! LaTeX Error: Environment sanskrit undefined.`

Comment: Thanks for your help! Hm, I tried the code again. I don't geht the Error message Environment "sanskrit" undefined. Maybe a thing with the sanskrit fonts?

Comment: Would it be working with "minipage"?

Comment: I can not run the example as posted, but margin notes will not breal there are packages specially designed for parallel translation eg the `parallel` package

Answer (score 1):

So I tried now with parallel package. Comes better like this.

[image]

One question: is it possible to change the distance between A, B, C? It is not possible with the commands \par\smallskip or \vspace. I would like to make the distance smaller. Could I define \ in the preambel without changing the distance of the lines?

My code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{reledmac}% Nummerierung
\usepackage{multicol} % just to get narrow columns on one page
\usepackage{fontspec}


%Paralleler Text
\usepackage{parallel}

\newcommand{\start}{\begin{Parallel}{0.47\textwidth}{0.47\textwidth}}

%marginnote
\newcommand{\RText}[1]{\ParallelRText{{\textit{{#1}}}}}

%Definition Paragraph
\newcommand{\LText}[3]{\ParallelLText{{\begin{sanskrit}\textbf{#1}\end{sanskrit}}\\

{\textbf{#2}}\\

#3\\\\}}


\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text} % ditto
\setmainfont{Gandhari Unicode} %could be any Unicode font

\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage{english}
    \setotherlanguage{sanskrit}% some Sanskrit embedded in it.
% These will call appropriate hyphenation.
    \newfontfamily\devanagarifont{Sanskrit 2003}

\usepackage{geometry}     
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
\subtitel{gaṇeśa gāyatrī}{Gāyatrī-Mantra auf Gaṇeśa}{\textbf{Gaṇa}: göttliche Heerscharen. \textbf{Īśa}: Herr, Meister, Göttlichkeit; besitzen. \textbf{Gāyatrī}: Name einer berühmten Klasse von Mantras.}


\start
\LText{ॐ तत् पुरुषाय विद्महे वक्रतुण्डाय धीमहि।
\\
तन्नो दन्ती प्रचोदयात्॥}{oṃ tat puruṣāya vidmahe vakratuṇḍāya dhīmahi\\
tanno dantī pracodayāt}{Mögen wir Wissenheit über die bezeugende Instanz erlangen,
mögen wir unsere Aufmerksamkeit auf den mit dem gebogenen Rüssel halten, möge uns der mit den Stosszähnen zum Ziele führen.}

\RText{\textbf{Tad}: dieser. \textbf{Puruṣa}: Mensch, die Essenz des Menschen. \textbf{Vidhmahe}: [1. Pers. Pl. Pres. c2 Atm.: √vid] möge ich finden, entdecken,
erhalten, wissen, fühlen. \textbf{Vakra}: gebogen, verdreht. \textbf{Tuṇḍa}: Rüssel. \textbf{Dhīmahe}: [1. Pers. Pl. Opt. C4: √dhī] halten, platzieren; den Geist auf etwas ausrichten. \textbf{Tad}: dieser. \textbf{Nas}: uns. \textbf{Dantī}: Stosszähne habend. \textbf{Pracodayāt}: [3. Pers. Opt.] antreiben, anstiften, ermutigen, induzieren, überzeugen, ankündigen, inspirieren, zum Ziel führen.}
\end{Parallel}

\end{document}
```

Any suggestions?

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPHw2.png
```